# How to resize Jquery ui buttonset and change color of hover

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm attempting to apply a jQuery UI theme to my ASP.NET radio button list which I have done successfully but the font and size of the buttonset is way too big, how can I reduce the size of the button set?

I was also wondering if it's hard to change the color of the default selected button and the color when hovering over a button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the hover question, but I was struggling just now to scale down my buttonset size. There's probably no way to get jQuery UI to do the hard work, but I got what I wanted by adding a couple CSS tweaks to my page.

```
<style>
.ui-widget
{
    font-size: 10pt; /* originally something huge */
}

.ui-button
{
    margin-right: -0.5em !important; /* originally -0.3em */
}
</style>
```

Change font-size to suit you and then change margin-right until space between the buttons is gone.